# Pip install psycopg2 failing

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 on Mac with `sudo pip3 install psycopg2`, however I'm receiving the following warning message and error:

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/matthewbell/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/matthewbell/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/7e/93c325482c328619870b6cd09370f6dbe1148283daca65115cd63642e60f/psycopg2-2.8.2.tar.gz (368kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 368kB 1.9MB/s 
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-ijzzlh1o/psycopg2/
```

I think I must be missing something, why is it throwing this error?

Comment: `Error: pg_config executable not found.` Seems pretty clear

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, how do I get the pg_config executable?

Comment: see the linked duplicate